# Querying for array containment against a JSON column in PostgreSQL 9.3

Tags: json, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I'm running PostgreSQL 9.3. I have a column named "model" of type "json" (*not* jsonb). The content of the "model" column resembles the following:

`{
    "section": {
        "colors": ["red", "blue", "green"]
    }
}`

Is it possible to query for rows where `model -> section -> colors` contains "blue"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no json comparison operators in 9.3. You can call the function `json_array_elements()` and cast results of the function to `text`. `Distinct on` used in case the json arrays contain duplicated elements:

```
select distinct on (id) t.*
from my_table t,
json_array_elements(model->'section'->'colors')
where value::text = '"blue"';
```

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/f5eb7/2)

Comment: This is the correct answer. I ended up migrating to version 9.4.